# Why would someone have prepended and appended the empty string to an argument in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

I have inherited a set of scripts that have this kind of thing all over the place:

```
coalesce(''+ColumnName+'', '')
```

I understand the use of coalesce, but is there a good reason it is not simply this instead?

```
coalesce(ColumnName, '')
```

Comment: What specific datatype is ColumnName? Is it a nullable column? (Yeah, probably, I'm just checking.)

Comment: You need to provide more information (and some context about the snippet you posted) before we can answer this question. Can you edit your question to do so? Thanks.

Comment: You're 100% sure that the quotes are empty?

Comment: @PhilipKelley, they are nullable (n)varchars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are completely right, coalesce(ColumnName, '') is equivalent to coalesce(''+ColumnName+'', '') Whatever the ColumnName is of datatype varchar/char equivalent or not.
COALESCE returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Comment: What about data type convertions ?

Comment: No conversion occures to ColumnName concatenating it with ''.
SELECT 1+(coalesce(''+5+'', ''))
Returns 6
SELECT 1+(coalesce(5, ''))
Returns 6 also

Comment: To be also sure that (''+5+'') never get converted into char string equivalent, try this:
SELECT 'test:' + (coalesce(''+5+'', ''))
This through error:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test:' to data type int.

Comment: Atheer, I will agree with you, although this is happening just by luck. Actually, int (that you use) has a higher precedence than varchar. If you were to use for example varbinary (or binary) etc then it would be converted to varchar as in that case varchar has greater precedence.

Comment: George, binary and varbinary won't get converted to varchar by concatenation, they already don't support the add operator and will through this error:
"The data types varchar and binary are incompatible in the add operator."
Notice: it's a mistake found in SQL Engine 2012 error messages, it should say "types varbinary and binary", but it said by mistake varchar LOL